# lines of a SpatialLinesDataFrame corresponding to points

Tags: r, spatial-database, sf

I have a spatial lines data frame which can be projected on to a map. The projection is defined as WGS84. I have a Spatial Points Data Frame which is also in the same location.

How can I isolate the streets/lines in the line data frame which contain, or are close to, a point in the points dataframe.

[image: These are the points]

[image: These are the lines]

I am not able to see the geometry of the lines described in the Spatial Lines Dataframe.

Comment: You can buffer the points into polygons according to the distance you need and then check which lines intersect with those polygons. The buffering can be done with `rgeos:gBuffer` and the intersection with `rgeos:gintersection`.

Answer (score 2):

Get package `sf`, cast your sp objects to sf objects using `y <- st_as_sf(x)`, and do something like

```
library(sf)    

# some demo points
pts <- list(st_point(c(1,1)), st_point(c(2,1)), st_point(c(3.5,3.1)), 
            st_point(c(4.5,5)), st_point(c(3.6,3.1))) %>%
  st_sfc() %>% st_sf()

# and some demo nearby lines    
lns <- list(st_linestring(matrix(c(5,3, 3,3, 3,2), byrow = T, ncol = 2)),
            st_linestring(matrix(c(1.1, 1.1, 2.9, 2), byrow = T, ncol = 2)),
            st_linestring(matrix(c(4,5,5,5), byrow = T, ncol = 2))) %>% 
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_sf()

# have a look
plot(lns)
plot(pts, add = TRUE, col = 'grey50')

# return a sparse matrix of proximities
prox <- st_is_within_distance(pts, lns, dist = 0.11)

# or a dense one (rows = lns, cols = pts)
prox_d <- st_distance(lns, pts) <= 0.11

# subset the original lines with the sparse matrix
lns_w_nearby_pts <- lns[unique(unlist(prox)), ]

# or the dense one
lns_w_nearby_pts_d <- lns[apply(prox_d, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) any(x == TRUE)), ]

identical(lns_w_nearby_pts, lns_w_nearby_pts_d) # == TRUE \o/

# check the results with e.g.
plot(lns_w_nearby_pts_d, add = TRUE, col = 'red')
```